# Get ListPicker SelectedItem value

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone

I have a `ListPicker` bound to Anonymous type List and want to get value of it. This is the code:

```
Dim listZoneSrc = From zon In listZone
               Join joinCZ In listJoinCityZone On
               joinCZ.zoneId Equals zon.zoneId
               Where joinCZ.cityId = cityId
               Select zon.zoneId, zon.zoneName, joinCZ.price

lpickZone.ItemsSource = listZoneSrc.ToList
```

Is it possible to get value of `lpickZone.SelectedItem.zoneId` in `lpickZone_SelectionChanged` Sub?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth

Comment: Thanks Wesley, but this is different case. I have bound ListPicker to LINQ result as List so my question would be is it right way to bind ListPicker and if so, how to get selected value.